# React: Using a redux export connect from other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form

I'm writing a mobile app with React Native. I have two js files as following:

Error.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTranslate } from 'react-localize-redux';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      t: getTranslate(state.locale)
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(
    ({ t }) => ({
        e001: t('wrong_format'),
        e002: t('invalid_email'),
    })
);
```

SignIn.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTranslate } from 'react-localize-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import Error from './Error';

const validate = (values) => {
    console.log('error: ', Error);
    // Process validate redux-form with messages from Error.js
};

class SignIn extends Component {
    // Process login form with redux-form
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        t: getTranslate(state.locale),
    };
}

const SignInForm = {
    form: 'SignIn',
    validate,
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(
    reduxForm(SignInForm)(
        SignIn
    )
);
```

How can I use the data that exported from Error.js in SignIn.js? (e.g. values of 'e001', 'e002')

Example from validate function (in SignIn.js) I wanna show the value of code "e001" from Error.js.

For more detail, my idea is collect all error messages from language file (using react-localize-redux) into Error.js, then from validate functions of redux-form, i can show those messages easier.

Answer (score 0):

Its look like you want `Error.js` as a helper file.But you are implemented it as react-redux container.

If you implementing it as react-redux container then necessarily it will call every time whenever store  will change.

Instead simply export it.

```
import { getTranslate } from 'react-localize-redux';

    const format = ({
                    e001: getTranslate('wrong_format'),
                    e002: getTranslate('invalid_email'),
                  })

export default format;
```

Called it as once imported

```
console.log(format.e001);
```

Comment: Yes, i am. I'm implementing react-redux for language and redux-form as well. As you solution i can use in normal case but with redux i can't. You can see `{ t }` is  from `t: getTranslate(state.locale)` from my code. With your solution I can't call `t('wrong_format')` (need to connect to redux store)

Comment: from where the `t` is coming,any package?

Comment: `t` is from `mapStateToProps`. You can see on Error.js. Actually I use `react-localize-redux` package to manage languages, so `t` is the props of `getTranslate` function from the package @RIYAJ KHAN

Comment: Thanks for your help @RIYAJ KHAN, but the solution didn't work for me. I got the error when calling `getTranslate` directly like that. Screenshot of error: http://prntscr.com/jx3dmx

Comment: Its not related to this.May package dependancy